# Whats the code for button action?

Tags: swift, cosmicmind

Me again, I'm loving this library but running into minor issues here and there.

For `RaisedButton`, what code is needed to create an action when the button is create programatically?

`btn1.addTarget(self, action: "okButton", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)`

```
func okButton(sender:RaisedButton!) {
    print("button pressed")
}
```

results in `unrecognized selector sent to instance`.

Comment: Does "okButton:" work?

Comment: No, I have tried the colon as well.

Comment: Is `okButton(_:)` in the same view controller as where you add the target? And if `okButton(_:)` expects a parameter, you'll have to add the colon.

Comment: My error, I had it outside of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code remove the unwrapping of the optional parameter:

```
func okButton(sender: RaisedButton) {
    print("button pressed")
}
```

Add the ":" at the end of your selector name:

```
btn1.addTarget(self, action: "okButton:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

That should solve your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to give "okButton:" as action as it takes an argument.

Try:

```
btn1.addTarget(self, action: "okButton:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
```